Stop the default multi-factor enrolment notification email template
I am in the process of customizing all of the auth flows in firebase using my own backend emailing service. I have been successful customizing all of them and have a custom multi-factor enrolment notification ready and working.
My question is, how can I stop the default multi-factor enrolment notification from triggering whenever I enrol a new multi-factor?
Here is the code I'm running to enrol a sms 2-fa:
class AuthService {
  AuthService(this._firebaseAuth, this._googleSignIn);

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  FirebaseAuth get firebaseAuth => _firebaseAuth;

  Future<void> enrollSms2fa(
    String phoneNumber,
    BuildContext context,
    final VoidCallback onSuccess,
    final VoidCallback stopProcessing,
    final void Function(String) onError,
  ) async {
    final session = await 
  _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.multiFactor.getSession();
    await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      multiFactorSession: session,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (_) {},
      verificationFailed: (e) {
        onError('${e.message}');
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        final smsCode = await getSmsCodeFromUser(context);

        if (smsCode != null) {
          final credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
            verificationId: verificationId,
            smsCode: smsCode,
          );

          try {
            await _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.multiFactor.enroll(
              PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.getAssertion(
                credential,
              ),
              displayName: phoneNumber,
            );
            onSuccess();
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
            onError('${e.message}');
            if (context.mounted) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
            stopProcessing();
            String? errorMessage;
            if ('${e.message}'.contains("Firebase:")) {
              errorMessage = '${e.message}'.split('Firebase: ')[1];
            }
            onError(errorMessage!);
          } catch (e) {
            onError('$e');
            if (context.mounted) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
            stopProcessing();
            onError('$e');
          }
        }
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (e) {
        onError(e.toString());
      },
    );
  }
}

I don't want to send the default email as I have my own custom one I want to use. And If I can't disable the default one the user will receive two different emails.
I've tried reading through all the docs but can't seem to find anything relevant to enrolling and skipping the email notification.
